# IdentityServer4 multiple WSFederation-providers cause an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, ws-federation

I was told that the [issue](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1855#event-1384066701) I will describe here is not a bug in the IdentityServer, so I'm probably doing something wrong:

This code works, using a single WSFederation-instance as identity provider in the [QuickStart-project using EFCore](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage).

Registering the provider:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddWsFederation("WsFederation", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.Wtrealm = realm;
                options.MetadataAddress = metadata;
                options.Events.OnTicketReceived += OnTicketReceived;
            })
```

OnTicketReceived-Eventhandler:

```
/// <summary>
/// Transform the UPN-claim to the sub-claim to be compatible with IdentityServer4
/// </summary>
private async Task OnTicketReceived(TicketReceivedContext ticketReceivedContext)
{
     var identity = ticketReceivedContext.Principal.Identities.First();
     identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", ticketReceivedContext.Principal.FindFirstValue("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier")));

}
```

As soon as I add a second provider, I will get an exception when trying to use the second provider, because the first provider added takes the request and throws an exception as soon as it receives the request:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddWsFederation("WsFederation_LocalHost", "WsFederation_LocalHost", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.Wtrealm = "urn:aspnetcorerp";
                    options.MetadataAddress = "http://localhost:5000/wsfederation";
                    options.Events.OnTicketReceived += OnTicketReceived;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                })
                .AddWsFederation("WsFederation_SVN", "WsFederation_SVN", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.Wtrealm = realm;
                    options.MetadataAddress = metadata;
                    options.Events.OnTicketReceived += OnTicketReceived;
                    options.Events.OnSecurityTokenReceived += OnSecurityTokenReceived;
                })
```

The exception I get is this - if I fix it by allowing unsolicited logins other exceptions will occure as it still tries to use the wrong provider:

> System.Exception: Unsolicited logins are not allowed.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.d__12.MoveNext()

I found the point where it is raised [in IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/81c9c0a428cf75307f20125843ac2a3d4221f5a1/src/IdentityServer4/Hosting/FederatedSignOut/AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.cs#L39):

```
public async Task<bool> HandleRequestAsync()
    {
var result = await _inner.HandleRequestAsync();
```

I can fix this if I change the above code to catch the Exception, as it will afterwards pass the correct provider and the login succeeds:

```
var result = false;
try
{
   result = await _inner.HandleRequestAsync();
}
catch (Exception) {}
```

I am not happy with having to fork IdentityServer4 to resolve this problem, so I am asking for a solution without changing the code of the IdentityServer. The place where I could step in and change something is either the configuration of my WSFederation-endpoint, right [before starting the ExternalLogin](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/051243bfd0dabc3b2e90722287a09231a237d9a6/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L143) or [at the callback](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/051243bfd0dabc3b2e90722287a09231a237d9a6/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L202) in the AccountController.

Callback in the AccountController:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback()
    {
        // read external identity from the temporary cookie - I don't know how I could change which AuthenticationMiddleware gets called
        var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
```

Any hints where I should start are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it - the solution is to set different CallbackPaths for the different providers:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddWsFederation("WsFederation_LocalHost", "WsFederation_LocalHost", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.Wtrealm = "urn:aspnetcorerp";
                    options.MetadataAddress = "http://localhost:5000/wsfederation";
                    options.Events.OnTicketReceived += OnWsFedTicketReceived;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-wsfed-localhost";
                })
                .AddWsFederation("WsFederation_SVN", "WsFederation_SVN", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.Wtrealm = realm;
                    options.MetadataAddress = metadata;
                    options.Events.OnTicketReceived += OnWsFedTicketReceived;
                    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-wsfed-svn";
                })
```

Comment: Hey, call back path can be any random name? like /signin-wsfed-svn-random? Just needs to be unique?

Comment: Yes, you can use a path of your choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This answer helped me a lot. Was searching for a solution since long time. I tried AllowUnsolicitedLogins as true but it seems to create problem, do you think AllowUnsolicitedLogins as true is alternative for this?

Comment: I don't know if this can help, but in addition to the problems you have this also will decrease the security so I would not recommend using it. I also always would go the way of using the features that are there and not try to implement workarounds as you could create more security issues with it.

Comment: This post saved me a lot of time. Thank you.